# = vs == in NSPredicate

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

I have seen in the apple document they have mentioned that `=`, `==` will behave same.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1

But in apple examples they use `==` in most cases and `=` for nil check.

Is it safe to use `=` for the below case?

```
NSPredicate(format: "firstName = %@", "Bunny")
```

or should we use:

```
NSPredicate(format: "firstName == %@", "Bunny")
```

Is there any difference between the two when dealing with predicates?

Answer (score 9):

They are equivalent when used in NSPredicate. I suppose there might be a slight preference for `==` since it would "look" more correct when combined with other Swift code. But either would be safe to use.